# Fractal-generating software for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, software

Could you please tell me what programs I could use to generate fractals? I am interested in relatively simple fractals like the Sierpinski Triangle. What I want is to be able to specify the number of fractal components a fractal is composed of, the scaling factors for each of those components, and to get a fractal upon providing that. What is also of interest to me is maybe specifying the dimension of a fractal I want and then just getting a fractal.

I need this software to run on Windows 10, and it should be free. I tried browsing the web in search of such software but all software I could find has an abundance of parameters to regulate in a fractal which I do not like.

Comment: Do you require stand-alone software for a specific platform, or will online resources meet your requirements? I searched "generate fractals" and received many returns, too many to list. What research have you performed on your own? Lack of research risks downvotes to your post.

Comment: Please add more focus, in particular: What OS, or online? Open source, gratis, etc? Output format?

Answer (score 0):

You can use NetLogo, desktop app for all OS (it comes with its own Java JRE).

Install it from https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo ,
Choose File Menu "Models Library"
Type "Fractals" to filter, the sidebar)
Choose one from the sidebar  (doubleclick on Model Name),
click "Setup" Button then "Go" button to start

[image]

Comment: I've tried this one. As far as I can tell, I does not allow for specifying just the number of self-similar copies and the scaling factors to get a fractal. Am I wrong? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: For example, I am looking for a fractal composed of 7 copies of itself, each half the size of the original. This would give dimension $\log_2 7$. But this by itself is not enough to specify a fractal in that program.

Comment: If your goal is to try say fewer than 10 steps, you can just click "Go" repeatedly. Make sure it does not have a double-arrow modifier-icon, if so remove that with right click) The ticks counter at top of page displays how many times you have clicked or calculation steps have been carried out. ----   Maybe take a look at the code for the Koch Curve or  Serpinski trangle and tweak those? See "Code" tab.

Comment: Could you please tell me if there is a way there to have a filled figure at the beginning and then have the iterations consecutively remove parts of it, just like for the Sierpinski Triangle?

Comment: I don't have the time, sorry. Perhaps try some more fractal generators for Netlogo by browsing the [modeling commons](http://modelingcommons.org/search/search_action), search for fractals there. Download + import some free Netlogo models